# Symfony router {_controller} param

Tags: php, symfony, routes

i'm new to Symfony. I'm trying to create dynamic universal route that will pick required controller based on part of url. I've found in docs that there is special param {_controller} that can be used in route pattern, but could not find any examples of usage.

```
// config/routes.yaml
api:
    path: /api/{_controller}
```

So for example for route `/api/product` i expect ProductController to be initiated.
But as a result i get error "**The controller for URI "/api/product" is not callable: Controller "product" does neither exist as service nor as class.**"

Can somebody please help me understanding how {_controller] param works? Or maybe there is a better way for specifying universal route that can dynamically chose controller without listing controller names in routes.yaml.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using a [controller event listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller) is probably the most straight forward approach to what you are trying to do.  You will probably need to spend a bit of time understanding the request/response process.  The fact that this sort of thing is not widely done might perhaps lead you to rethinking your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really the cleanest way to do what I think you're trying to do. If I am correct in assuming you want to have a `/api/product/` point to methods in your product controller, then something like this is more "symfonyish"

```
// src/Controller/ProductController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/api/product", name="product_")
 */
class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     * --Resolves to /api/product/
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/list", name="list")
     * --Resolves to /api/product/list
     */        
    public function list(): Response
    {
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{productID}", name="get")
     * --Resolves to /api/product/{productID}
     */        
    public function get(string $productID): Response
    {
        // $productID contains the string from the url
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that this really just scratches the surface of Symfony routing. You can also specify things like `methods={"POST"}` on the routing directive; so you could have the same path do different things depending on the type of request (e.g. you could have a route `/product/{productID}` that `GET`s the product on  that request but updates the product on a `PATCH` request.

Regardless, the takeaway here is that it is unwieldy to have all of your routes defined in `routes.yml` rather you should define your routes as directives in the controller itself.

Comment: Cool, but the question was about creating dynamic routes

Comment: @TheGentleman so, do i understand it right, that instead of creating some universal route that will cover all my 20 controllers, i should configure routing specifically for each controller, even if all controllers have many common parts and are extending my base rest controller?

Comment: @Serogia - you could create a generic route that does what you're describing using a [Dynamic Router](https://symfony.com/bundles/CMFRoutingBundle/current/routing-component/dynamic.html) but generally that isn't worth the trouble depending on you your use case.